# I come with a seal of approval

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I come before the end,
> I am not your friend.
>
> Brothers, have I three,
> They shall make you flee.
>
> The first is white,
> And ready to fight.
> Posies in his hand,
> All are sick upon the land.
>
> The second is red,
> Peace has fled.
> You call him to your aid,
> But his price must be paid.
>
> The third is black,
> You can only eat tack.
> He sucks that which you have,
> Leaving you with less than half.

Who am I?

Comment: http://image-cdn.neatoshop.com/styleimg/52927/none/lightturquoise/default/332261-19;1480214108i.jpg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are

> Death (or death's pale horse), among the [Four Horsemen of the Apocalypse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_Horsemen_of_the_Apocalypse). In the book of Revelations, breaking seals will cause the horsemen to appear; hence the puzzle's title.

`I come before the end,
I am not your friend.`

> Referring to the apocalypse. Death (or its horse) is not your friend.

`Brothers, have I three,
They shall make you flee.`

> There are three other riders besides Death: Pestilence (sometimes Conquest), War, and Famine.

`The first is white,
And ready to fight.
Posies in his hand,
All are sick upon the land.`

> Pestilence (disease, all are sick) rides a white horse. There are also [theories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_a_Ring_o%27_Roses) that posies were used to fend off plagues.

`The second is red,
Peace has fled.
You call him to your aid,
But his price must be paid.`

> War rides a red horse. There is no peace, so there is war.

`The third is black,
You can only eat tack.
He sucks that which you have,
Leaving you with less than half.`

> Famine rides a black horse. This stanza is referring to a food shortage.

Comment: Okay, I'm marking this as correct since it is spot on! Good job!